# css and js file source output instead of link to each file

Tags: php, wordpress

Would really appreciate some help with the above.
Currently have a dev site that is using WordPress as engine.
Recently, when viewing the source code, certain css and js required files are being output into the page source, instead of the usual link to each file.
This is creating a source file some 20000 lines long.

It doesnt happen when viewing on my localhst Xampp machine. 
Both sites are running the latest version of WordPress and Latest version of PHP.
Both are using exactly the same theme files too.
I just dont know why this is happening and wonder if anyone can shed light?

Live dev site is at [live dev site](http://mdjl.perfect10.property)

Also, just noticed, its not happening in Firefox.

Comment: Not happening in Chrome using Mac too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked right now and I see all CSS and JS is are usual links to files. And your page have only 356 lines.
Maybe you see the cached version of the website in your browser? Try to refresh with ctr+f5, try to clear all cache in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, its got me really baffled:

this is output on localhost site: <link rel='stylesheet' id='propertwise-css'  href='http://foxtons.dev/wp-content/themes/realproperty-child/style.css?ver=1.8.1' media='all' /> and this is output of live site: <style id="propertwise-css" media="all" style="display:none"> for the same file as example.  Could you help, unothodox maybe, but I see the same from a themes over on themeforest, well known site, same output, all in the source. view-source:http://realhomes.inspirythemes.biz/  could you see if you see the same.

Comment: At my side all ok with both websites. Do you try another browser from your computer?

Comment: Thanks Alex, Really strange and I appreciate you looking, even though there is not really a coding answer, thought it maybe a WordPress issue with wp_enqueue or wp_register, that was my worry.
It happens with chrome, explorer (both latest versions) but not Firefox. I'll have to see if I get a change on a different machine.

Comment: It's looking good in my Opera, IE, Chrome and FF, so I think it's not browser compatibility question.